# Use a file without knowing its full name

Tags: bash

I'm running a linux file system checksum on various devices with different operating systems. How do I make this bash script run without having knowledge of the check file names? In my case only one check file should in the folders location at any given time.

Here are my check files:

```
os_1.1.1.ck
os_1.23.1.ck
os_2.32.123.ck
```

Here is the script I'm trying to create:

```
#!/bin/bash
md5sum -c /home/test/*.ck > log.txt
wait
echo "We're done!"
```

Comment: Your script uses globbing (`*`) so the exact file names do not really need to be known already. Please explain expected vs actual behavior.

Comment: Ok so the `*` is what I'd use in my case?

Comment: I'm sorry, but it is completely unclear what you are trying to do. The checksum of which object(s) (did you really mean file systems?) should be calculated? Or should they be compared? To what? Why are you using the `-c` switch in your script? What are you trying to achieve with the `wait` statement?

Comment: As long as you can assume that there is *exactly* one file matching `*.ck` in  `/home/test`, this does what you want. You don't need the `wait` call, though, since you aren't waiting for any background processes to finish.

Comment: I'm waiting for the checksum of all of the files in the .ck file to complete.

Comment: Why are you using the `-c` option to `md5sum`? The purpose of that option is to check a given sum against the specified file. And you don't need to `wait` for things to finish. You're not sending it to the background, there's nothing to wait for.

Comment: No Mike and Michael you are wrong about `-c`... It reads MD5 sums from a file and compares them to the file systems md5sums. Execute this command `md5sum --help`. Also I am waiting for a process to complete. I'm waiting for the md5sum process to complete.

Comment: Commands don't return until they are finished normally. You don't send `md5sum` to the background so there's nothing to `wait` on. The `wait` does nothing for you. Also, however many `*.ck` files you have that script will correctly pass them as arguments to `m5dsum` so unless you know you are going to have many such files and only want some of them that should work just fine as-is.

Answer (score -2):

If all the files are .ck files you can list them :

```
for file in `ls -1 /home/test/`
do
md5sum -c /home/test/$file > log.txt
done
```

Comment: Please don't. [See bash pitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)